# C++ destructor behaviour

Tags: c++, destructor

I tried the following program on Visual Studio 2010.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
        int p;

        /*A(){
            cout << "Constructor A" << endl;
        }*/

        ~A(){
            cout << "Destructor in A" << endl;
        }
};

class D: public A
{
public: 

        /*D(){
            cout << "Constructor D" << endl;
        }*/

        ~D(){
            cout << "Destructor in D" << endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    D d =  D();
    cout << "Exiting main" << endl;
}
```

The output that I got was -

```
Destructor in D
Destructor in A
Exiting main
Destructor in D
Destructor in A
```

I am not able to understand why the destructor of class D and A are being called
before "Exiting main" statement is executed?

I tried another thing - I uncommented the Class D constructor in the code above, then the output was as I
expected -

```
Constructor D
Exiting main
Destructor in D
Destructor in A
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The line

```
D d =  D();
```

first creates a temporary, unnamed object, which then is copied to `d`. What you see is the temporary object being destroyed when the statement is ended. The named object `d` is destroyed when it goes out of scope, after `main()` is completed.

If you add a copy constructor to `D` you'll see that it is invoked.

When commenting out the constructor I think that you see the expected behaviour because the compiler can do some optimizations.

Comment: Doesn't explain why the second example doesn't print out the destructor calls anymore.

Comment: You could tell how it should be (:

Comment: The compiler is only allowed to make unobservable optimizations. Even if it does copy elision, the call should still be printed.

Comment: Hm, even with `O0`, gcc still does not create a temp object...interesting

Comment: @Xeo The C++ Standard says that compiler is allowed to elide the copy constructor in almost all cases, even when the copy constructor has side effects.

Comment: @Neil: I meant the destruction of the temporary.

Comment: Also, the compiler should be able to optimize the code even with the default constructor. Or am I missing something totally obvious here?

Comment: @Xeo: what? "When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit the copy/move construction of a class
object, even if the copy/move constructor and/or destructor for the object have side effects. In such cases,
the implementation treats the source and target of the omitted copy/move operation as simply two different
ways of referring to the same object, and the destruction of that object occurs at the later of the times
when the two objects would have been destroyed without the optimization."

Comment: I added the copy constructor to D - `D(const D& obj){
cout << "Inside D's copy constructor" << endl;}` but I dont see it being called, because I got the following `Constructor D
Exiting main`

Comment: @ybungalobill: Geh, showing yet again that code that relies on side-effects sucks. :)

Comment: @Shalmali: That is what happens when copy elision kicks in. Basically the compiler removes the temporary by placing it *on top of* the final variable. You can add `std::cout << this;` to the constructors and also print `&d` in `main` after construction and you will see that the default constructor of `D` is called on `d`. Note that it is still not equivalent to `D d;` (even in the presence of a default constructor) as the compiler has to verify that the copy constructor is accessible (even if it does not use it). In the first case the compiler did not elide the copy (I don't know why)